# UI not updating correctly on Android, toggles on 'Overview' click & app re-enter

Tags: android, label, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

In certain parts of my app the UI does not get updated. However in the same view that should be getting updated, when the Android 'Overview' button is clicked and it shows all the recent apps & windows and you reenter the app the UI is updated and I see all the text that was set on my labels. If I try the same thing again, it loads the page without the text on my labels as it was before. Hitting overview again and reentering app loads the text labels, so hitting overview and reentering the app essentially toggles the behavior.

It's a very strange behavior I've never encountered before and I'm not sure how to approach it so any help would be much appreciated.

I'm using Ti SDK 6.0.4.GA on Android 7.1 and I have not seen this same behavior when working on iOS.

Below is the code for a part of the app exhibiting the behavior.
filters.xml:

```
<Alloy>
<Window title="Search | Filters" id="container">
    <View id="content">
        <TableView id="filter_table" class="fillWidth">
            <HeaderView>
                <Label id="filter_header" text="Search Filters"/>
            </HeaderView>
            <TableViewRow layout="hgroup">
                <!-- Price Range -->
                <Label text="Price Range" top="5" class="subtitle"/>
                <View top="30" left="0" class="halfWrap">
                    <Label text="Minimum" id="minLbl" class="subtitle" />
                    <TextField id="priceMin" hintText="Min Price" class="priceField"></TextField>
                </View>
                <View top="30" right="0" class="halfWrap" >
                    <Label text="Maximum" id="maxLbl" class="subtitle" />   
                    <TextField id="priceMax" hintText="Max Price" class="priceField"></TextField>
                </View>
            </TableViewRow>
            <TableViewRow>
                <!-- Min. Beds -->
                <Label id="bedLbl" type="beds" text="Bedrooms" class="subtitle" />
                <Slider class="filterSlider" id="bedSlider" onChange="updateSliderLbl" />
            </TableViewRow>
            <TableViewRow>
                <!-- Min. Baths -->
                <Label id="bathLbl" type="baths" text="Bathrooms" class="subtitle" />
                <Slider class="filterSlider" id="bathSlider" onChange="updateSliderLbl" />
            </TableViewRow>
            <TableViewRow layout="horizontal">
                <!-- Property Type -->
                <Label text="Property Types" top="10" class="subtitle" />
                <View class="halfWrap" >
                    <Label text="Foreclosures" class="subtitle" />
                    <Switch id="foreSwitch" class="filterSwitch" ></Switch>
                </View>
                <View class="halfWrap" >
                    <Label text="Conventional" class="subtitle" />
                    <Switch id="convSwitch" class="filterSwitch" ></Switch> 
                </View>
            </TableViewRow>
        </TableView>
        <View id="btnGroup" >
            <View id="btnPad" >
                <Button class="button-default" id="applyBtn" onClick="setFilters" title="Apply Filters &\n Search"/>
            </View>
        </View>
    </View>
</Window>
```

filters.js:

```
// Arguments passed into this controller can be accessed via the `$.args` object directly or:
var args = $.args;
var Util = require('util');

checkPrevFilters();

/**
 * Updates the label associated with a slider to show the user it's value
 * @param {Object} e event object generated from change of Slider
 */
function updateSliderLbl(e){
//Util.dump(e.source);
try{
    var roundVal = Math.round(e.source.value);
}
catch(e){
    Ti.API.error(e);
}
var textToSet = roundVal; 
var label = e.source.getParent().children[0];
if(label.type == "beds")
    textToSet += "+ Bedrooms";
else if(label.type == "baths"){
    textToSet += "+ Bathrooms";
}
label.setText(textToSet);
}       

function showBeds(){
$.bedLbl.setText(Math.floor($.bedSlider.value)+"+ Bedrooms");
}

function showBaths(){
$.bathLbl.setText(Math.floor($.bathSlider.value)+"+ Bathrooms");
}

/**
 * Looks at the values of both the foreclosure and conventional property 
type switches and returns a value based
 * on the checkbox selection
 */
function getPropType(){
var fore_val = $.foreSwitch.getValue(); 
var conv_val = $.convSwitch.getValue();
var return_val;

switch(true){
    case(fore_val && conv_val):
        return_val = "";
        break;
    case(fore_val && !conv_val):
        return_val = "foreclosure";
        break;
    case(!fore_val && conv_val):
        return_val = "conventional";
        break;
}
fore_val = null; conv_val = null;
return return_val;
}

/**
 * 
 */
function checkPrevFilters(){
if(Ti.App.Properties.hasProperty('search_filters')){
    Ti.API.info("Previous Filters Found; Setting;");
    var filter_vals = Ti.App.Properties.getObject('search_filters');

    _.isUndefined(filter_vals.priceMin) ? $.priceMin.setValue('') : $.priceMin.setValue(filter_vals.priceMin);
    _.isUndefined(filter_vals.priceMax) ? $.priceMax.setValue('') : $.priceMax.setValue(filter_vals.priceMax);

    _.isUndefined(filter_vals.beds) ? $.bedSlider.setValue(0) : $.bedSlider.setValue(filter_vals.beds);
    _.isUndefined(filter_vals.baths) ? $.bathSlider.setValue(0) : $.bathSlider.setValue(filter_vals.baths);

    switch(!_.isUndefined(filter_vals.propType)){
        case(filter_vals.propType == "conventional"):
            $.convSwitch.setValue(true);
            $.foreSwitch.setValue(false);
            break;
        case(filter_vals.propType == "foreclosure"):
            $.foreSwitch.setValue(true);
            $.convSwitch.setValue(false);
            break;
        default:
            $.foreSwitch.setValue(true);
            $.convSwitch.setValue(true);
    }
}else
    Ti.API.info('No previous filters found.');
}

/**
 * Adds filters to the 
 * @param {Object} args
 */
function setFilters(){
var filters = {
    priceMin    : $.priceMin.getValue(),
    priceMax    : $.priceMax.getValue(),
    beds        : Math.floor($.bedSlider.getValue()),
    baths       : Math.floor($.bathSlider.getValue()),
    propType    : getPropType()
};
Ti.App.Properties.setObject("search_filters", filters);
var props = Alloy.createController('search_tab/props', args);
props.postFilterSearch(args.selection);
props = null;
closeFilters();
}

function closeFilters(){
$.container.setVisible(false);
$.container.close();
cleanup();
}

function cleanup(){
// let Alloy clean up listeners to global collections for data-binding
// always call it since it'll just be empty if there are none
$.destroy();

// remove all event listeners on the controller
$.removeListener();

// remove any listeners you added to global proxies
//Ti.Gesture.removeEventListener('orientationchange', onOrientationChange);

// and custom global dispatchers (all at once, via context)
//myDispatcher.off(null, null, $);

// in turn, let controllers of required views clean up

// and close windows of controllers you created, triggering them to clean up as well
//someWindow.getView().close();

// this is not needed if someController cleans up well and we have the only reference
// someController = null;
}

//Export functions
exports.cleanup = cleanup;
```

and here are a couple screenshots:
[image: this is the behavior where the UI is not updated]

[image: same view, but after having hit the Android 'Overview' button and reentering app]

Comment: Share the code of one of your screens that are not getting updated.

Comment: Added the code blocks and a couple screenshots